# Django Url.py Parameters

Tags: python, regex, django, view, url-routing

I followed the Django tutorial on how to use the url dispatcher, but for the life of me cannot figure out why I am getting this error.

> Reverse for 'details' with arguments '('my_address',)' and keyword
>   arguments 
>       '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['details(?P[0-9]+)/$']

My url.py:

```
url(r'^details(?P<zip>[0-9]+)/$', views.search_details, name='details'),
```

The url used in my template:

```
<h1><a href="{% url 'details' data.zip%}">Data for {{data.zip}}</a></h1>
```

My view method declaration:

```
def search_details(request,zip):
```

When I try remove the parameter(zip) from the above code, the template renders, so I would believe the url is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `zip` parameter matches digits from 0 to 9. The string "my_address" is not made up of those digits.

You should either pass a real zip, assuming those actually are numeric rather than alphabetic, or use a different pattern such as `\w+`.

Comment: You are a godsend! Thank you so much, I'll accept when able!

Answer (score 0):

I think your missing / after details:

```
url(r'^details/(?P<zip>[0-9]+)/$', views.search_details, name='details'),
```